# E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution) libreoffice

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, dependencies, libreoffice

Every time I try to upgrade it shows me this message

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-base-core : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-base-drivers : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-gnome : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-gtk3 : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-impress : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-math : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-ogltrans : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 openjdk-11-jre : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless (= 11.0.4+11-1ubuntu2~18.04.3) but 10.0.2+13-1ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) but 1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Have you? That command literally never works.

Comment: @Cerin - I've switched to an Arch-based distro since that post. When using Linux Mint, I did have to use that command a couple of times. Maybe **sicvolo's** answer will work for you.

Answer (score 31):

In certain cases you might also want to force the overwrite

`sudo dpkg --configure --force-overwrite -a`

Alternatively:

`sudo apt -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" --fix-broken install`

Comment: I scoured all over the internet to find this solution. :)

Comment: `Dpkg` really helped!

Comment: it's frustrating that this issue breaks the whole sytem update system. `sudo dpkg --configure --force-overwrite -a` was the solution: just beware that the things it lists as broken may indeed break: Tolerable if getting the rest of the system updated is in fact more urgent (as it often is, otherwise you miss security-critical updates).
Issue affects far more than just libreoffice.

Comment: thanks a lot. alternative solution worked for me

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Is not valid command for apt v.1.6.12. What should help is:

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

or

```
sudo apt reinstall
```

Comment: Given that `apt` itself suggests `apt --fix-broken install`, I think it’s safe to assume that variant works. `apt reinstall` won’t work on its own, it needs to be told what package to reinstall.

Comment: thank you, this worked

Comment: @StephenKitt apt still suggests the same, but wouldn't execute and give the help menu every time I execute `apt --fix-broken install`, but as suggested in the answer, `apt install --fix-broken` works perfectly fine and fixes everything.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel what version of `apt` do you have?

Comment: @StephenKitt 2.0.6

Answer (score 3):

Try these out:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I tried the first one many times but it seems is not working properly, i get this all the time

Comment: it wont let me use sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: You can try deleting the lock files if present.

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`